# Como utilizar acento agudo dentro de uma string em um script bash?

Tags: ubuntu, codificação-de-caracteres, bash, script, wget

Utilizo o script abaixo para baixar audios do google tradutor para usar em um programa pessoal que narra códigos e quantidades do meu estoque. O problema é que o acento agudo do "ó" da palavra código está trazendo um áudio com falha, como se estivesse com erro de encode. Se tentar direto pelo site do google tradutor dá certo, fala código direito.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'iniciando program'
while read line; do 
    echo $line
    wget -q -U Mozilla "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=código: $line" -O $line.mp3
    break
done < codigos.txt
echo 'fim'
```

Vocês podem tentar assim também:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'iniciando program'
wget -q -U Mozilla "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=código: 3 5 6. 05 unidades" -O teste.mp3
echo 'fim'
```

Comment: Thalysson, deu certo?

Comment: Deu certo sim! :D Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez seja necessário especificar a versão do *Mozilla* a ser usada, por exemplo `Mozilla/5.0`. [**Aqui**](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mozilla/) existem outras opções.

O segundo exemplo ficará assim:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo 'iniciando program'
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" -q "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=pt&q=código 3 5 6. 05 unidades" -O teste.mp3
echo 'fim'
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, fiz o mesmo e funcionou... mas o Qmechanic73 foi mais rápido... rsrsrs